# Workflow Foundation - what is the purpose of "value" for ResumeBookmark

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation-4

I'm now introducing myself to Workflow Foundation (WF) (.NET 4.6).
I have gone through some tutorials and read some documentation. 
However, I don't understand the purpose of the `value` argument of the method `WorkflowApplication.ResumeBookmark`. Each one of its versions gets an input "value" argument. What is the purpose of this "value"?
I've implemented some example applications with bookmarks and also read the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee149789(v=vs.110).aspx), which only says:

> ```
> An object passed as a parameter to the method that is invoked when the bookmark resumes.
> ```

Can anyone explain what could be a reasonable best-practice scenario that uses it?

Comment: Simple scenario is a user-id of the user that resumed the workflow. Or a reason when an approved-bookmark is resumed. It can be anything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "value" can be any object type.

So, perhaps you have a workflow that persists while waiting for an operation to return some data, e.g. Loan Approval

On ResumeBookmark you then package that data into an object and send the object into the resumed Activity.
The activity then uses the object to perform more actions e.g. steer the workflow based on if the loan was approved or not.